# SQL update query with MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I don't see anything that really seems the same to me on here, though it might be just me having not done sql in so long.

So I have a master table TestTempGeneralInfo and a dail TestTaskGeneralInfo. I can use this query:

```
SELECT testtempgeneralinfo.issueid, 
       Max(testtaskgeneralinfo.effectivetime) 
FROM   testtaskgeneralinfo 
       INNER JOIN testtempgeneralinfo 
               ON testtaskgeneralinfo.testtemplateid = 
                  testtempgeneralinfo.issueid 
WHERE  testtempgeneralinfo.projectid = 150 
GROUP  BY testtempgeneralinfo.issueid
```

To view the MAX of the TestTaskGeneralInfo tables effective time.

But I am struggling to write a query to update the same column TestTempGeneralInfo. Can anyone help? Hope this is not a dumb question. Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to store the MAX in any column? So that you can maintain it across all rows any time you add/update/delete any row? When you want to know the max value, just run the query that you already have. There is no reason to store this information.

Comment: You *can't* update a value returned by an expression or aggregate function. Specifically, the value returned by `Max(testtaskgeneralinfo.effectivetime)` returns the maximum value *stored* in the `effectivetime` field in the `testtaskgeneralinfo`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to do it, but the simplest for you may be to just take the query you have above and make it into a common table expression and then make your update statement join to the CTE:

```
    ;WITH MaxDate AS
    ( SELECT testtemplateid, Max(effectivetime) as MaxEffectiveTime
      FROM testtaskgeneralinfo
      GROUP BY testtemplateid)
    UPDATE testtempgeneralinfo 
    SET effectivetime = MaxEffectiveTime
    FROM   MaxDate 
    INNER JOIN testtempgeneralinfo 
           ON MaxDate.testtemplateid = testtempgeneralinfo.issueid 
    WHERE  testtempgeneralinfo.projectid = 150
```

EDIT: Sorry, had a bit of a copy/paste error there. But the above is assuming that you're wanting to update testtempgeneralinfo's effective time with the most recent testtaskgeneralinfo's effective time.

Comment: That's the name of the CTE. Could have done it the other way and had testtempgeneralinfo first, but it works either way.

Comment: What I get for typing in a hurry. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  I understand it to be:

*"Given the above query, how can I update the row that contains the maximum effectivetime with new values?"*

Assuming issueid is your primary key, the answer would be something like this:

```
update testtempgeneralinfo
set
  effectivetime = getdate()  --columns and values will vary...
where issueid = (
  SELECT top 1 testtempgeneralinfo.issueid
  FROM
    testtaskgeneralinfo 
    INNER JOIN
    testtempgeneralinfo 
    ON testtaskgeneralinfo.testtemplateid = testtempgeneralinfo.issueid 
    WHERE testtempgeneralinfo.projectid = 150 
    order by
      testtaskgeneralinfo.effectivetime desc
  );
```